# Customize Chart.js Tooltip and y-axis Label Positions

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following chart as in the picture below:

[image: Current Chart]

I basically want to modify the areas marked in red. I would like to combine the y-axis labels to display the labels on top of each others instead of inlining them as it is now (See the second image for illustration).

As for the tooltip, I did some customization to the background color and managed to hide the title using callbacks. However, I need to hide the legends in the tooltip or at least be able to change their shape to a circle instead of the default square. I also need to display each label with a color corresponding to the y-label color and a prefix or suffix similar to that of the y-label. (See the second image for illustration).

[image: Second Image]

This is my current tooltip configuration:

```
tooltips: {
            mode: "label",
            titleMarginBottom: 8,
            bodySpacing: 8,
            xPadding: 15,
            yPadding: 10,
            cornerRadius: 2,
            bodyFontStyle: "bold",
            backgroundColor: "#fcfcfc",
            titleFontColor: "#3a3938",
            bodyFontColor: "#3a3938",
            callbacks: {
                // this adds the same suffix to all labels. I would like the same suffix of prefix value from the y-axis label
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    return tooltipItems.yLabel + ' $';
                },
                title: function() {
                    return false;
                },
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you figured it out?